# Django CSRF cookie not set by JS post request

Tags: django, cookies, csrf

I'm trying to build client/server system as follows: server is django REST with some database, client is static HTML/CSS/JS built as separate django project.

I've got stuck with a basic user authentication scheme processed via simple login form on client side. My idea was to go for token authentication, token to be stored in client's localStorage - so that's why I've taken approach to handle the form submit and POST for token to server by JS.

The issue is I cannot get the token from server to client due to `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /getToken/` error on the server side. Spent tons of time on it and I cannot find answer why CSRF cookie is not set as I enforce at least 4 mechanisms forcing the cookie set: 1) `{% csrf_token %}`, 2) manual setting of cookie header, 3) `@ensure_csrf_cookie`, 4) removing `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in server settings.py ...

Here are the details:

The **client part** looks as follows:

- **login.html** form:

  ```
  <form name="login" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          Username<input type="text" name="uname"/>
          Password<input type="password" name="psswd"/>
          <input type="button" onclick="do_login(this.form)" value="Login"/>
          <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
  </form>
  ```

  where `do_login()` is in the script below. Pls mind the `{% csrf_token %}` is included ...
- **login_script.js** :

  ```
  function do_login(form) {
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    uname = form.uname.value;
    psswd = form.psswd.value;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/getToken/";

    var params = JSON.stringify({ username: uname, password: psswd });
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && req.status == 200) {
          alert(http.responseText);
      }
    }
    req.send(params);}
  ```

where `getCookie` is a copy&paste function from django tutorial (it seems to return some cookie, so I assume it's correct)

- **views.py**:

  ```
  @ensure_csrf_cookie
  def user_login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html', {})enter code here
  ```

I put `@ensure_csrf_cookie` to force the cookie input but with no success ...

On the **server side** I have a view

```
@require_POST
def getToken(request):
  serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
  serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  user = serializer.validated_data['user']
  token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  response = HttpResponse({'token': token.key}, content_type="application/json")
  response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
return response
```

which is basically the slightly redefined django's built-in `obtain_auth_token` (as I couldn't overcome CORS issue in any other way round)